# Touchpad isn't working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, dell, touchpad, mouse-pointer

I've recently bought a new laptop (Dell Venue 11 Pro), which can also be turned into a tablet with a removable keyboard and touchpad.

However, the touchpad isn't working and also the cursor is not shown. I have to use the touch screen for all of my work.

Comment: Did it stop working after some update? Or is it not working since installation? Sometimes new devices are better supported by a newer kernel, so you check if Ubuntu 20.10 works better with your hardware.

Comment: it works on lockscreen but as soon as i unlock my laptop it just stop working, and i have not updated my laptop

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if touchpad is detected via the command `sudo lspci | grep synaptics` or `sudo lspci | grep elantech` ,

It should show synaptics  or elantech or whatever brand (in which case replace the last word according to manufacturer in the above lspci | grep brand).May need to find the drivers and install them or recompile the kernel drivers ,if memory serves me correctly.

2. Do this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w39mvMeAxDw

Required restart, though (unlike in the video).

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad click-method areas`

`sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool`

`gnome-tweaks`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a bit destructive, but you could try reinstalling Ubuntu. Remember to back up your data first if you try this, and try other less destructive suggestions first. If you've changed any settings, put them back to how they were originally and try GNOME Tweaks for settings that aren't normally accessible.

Comment: In case it does not work right since fresh installation, this solution won't work.

Comment: yes sir it is not working after the fresh instalation